# Why does iOSOpenDev couldn't find LAActivator.h?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, jailbreak

When I use the fresh "Activator Listener" template(iOSOpenDev v1.6-2)  it meets the error "'LAActivator.h' file not found" , I've added the libactivator.dylib and done nothing else, What the matter maybe with it?

And I remember there was many framework headers inside /opt/iOSOpenDev/frameworks/ before I upgraded to v1.6-2, but there is nothing in the frameworks directory in this version, has it changed something?Or was my installation right?I didn't met any error in the installation.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't see anything in Frameworks, but under the `include` directory, there is a `"libactivator.h"` file (note all lower case).  Are you #importing `LAActivator.h`?  Can you try changing your code to `#import <libactivator/libactivator.h>`?  That's where I see the `LAActivator` interface.

Comment: Thank you @Nate. My testing project was generated from the `Activator Listener` template by iOSOpenDev default and I just followed the prompts to add the libactivator.dylib and did nothing else.Then it came the error. Could you take a look at my code?https://github.com/kevinzheng/TestA/tree/master/TestA

Comment: And I tried to copy the `libactivation.h` from project `libctivator` to override the one of `iOSOpenDev` default, The error didn't appear again, but crash when I tested in my iPhone.

Comment: ok, well if it's crashing, then you are now having a **different** problem.  Did your old code reference `LAActivator.h` directly?  Did you change it to `#import <libactivator/libactivator.h>` as I suggested, or was your code already like that?

Comment: I've imported `<libactivator/libactivator.h>` in my code.In old version of `libactivator.h`,it defined many stuff needed such as `LAActivator` class.But in the latest version of iOSOpenDev, there are only a few `import` codes, that's the place where it imports `LAActivator.h` and throws the error.If I just use the environment setup by iOSOpenDev, it couldn't find the `LAActivator.h` and no where provides this file. If I override this `<libactivator/libactivator.h>` by the version of `libactivator` projecet, this error is fixed, but it crashs.So I can't understand why iOSOpenDev did like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon install of iOSOpenDev, git repo https://github.com/kokoabim/iOSOpenDev is cloned to /opt/iOSOpenDev which contains an include directory that contains a libactivator directory which contains the libactivator.h file you are speaking of. Why is it not found, I am not sure. You could manually place the libactivator.h file on your system in a directory at /opt/iOSOpenDev/include/libactivator as iOSOpenDev Xcode templates search the include directory, and sub-directories, for header files.

Maybe there is a bug I am unaware of that is causing problems during cloning of this repo during installation. I would need to look into this further to determine if that is the case. But for now, all you need to do is get the libactivator.h file placed properly on your system.

UPDATE:

I see what the problem is. libactivator.h only has import statements to files that are not present. Previously this file contained code, now it only contains import statements. A fix is coming to resolve this.

UPDATE #2:

Added missing files to git repo https://github.com/kokoabim/iOSOpenDev. Re-running iOSOpenDev installation should resolve your issue.